# Cleaning noise out of Java stack traces

Tags: java, exception, stack-trace

My Java stack traces have a lot of entries that I don't care about, showing method invocation going through proxies and Spring reflection methods and stuff like that. It can make it pretty hard to pick out the part of the stack trace that's actually from my code. Ruby on Rails includes a "stack trace cleaner" where you can specify a list of stack trace patterns to omit from printed stack traces - what's the best way to do something like that, universally, for Java?

It'd be best if this worked everywhere, including in the Eclipse jUnit runner.

Comment: Ah yes, the "stack trace from hell" according to Cay Horstmann: https://plus.google.com/+CayHorstmann/posts/YAwGCVpLXgH

Comment: It would be great if there was a command line too. That would make looking through `catalina.log` less cumbersome.

Comment: @PhilipDurbin Google plus is closed. Any other link?

Comment: @gaurav I think this "Stack Trace From Hell" is the same (but I don't remember): http://horstmann.com/unblog/2006-06-07/netbeans-jsf.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[eclipse](/questions/tagged/eclipse) has a preference **Stack trace filter patterns** (look at *java* > *junit* or search for `stacktrace` in the preferences). You can ignore packages (also with wildcards), classes or methods. Does work for direct Test calls (via *Run as [junit](/questions/tagged/junit) Test*), not for commandline runs like `ant` or `maven`.

Comment: Thanks for this! This definitely solves my jUnit plugin problem.

Answer (score 17):

[intellij-idea](/questions/tagged/intellij-idea) allows customizable [stack trace folding](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/07/console-folding-customization/), especially useful with [dynamic languages](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/03/groovy-stacktrace-folding/).

[image: IntelliJ]
<sub>(source: [jetbrains.com](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/screen-shot-2010-07-12-at-100921-pm.png))</sub>

and an [Analyzing external stack traces](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2006/08/analyzing-external-stack-traces/) tool.

I can imagine general tool/filter working on logging framework (like [logback](/questions/tagged/logback) or [log4j](/questions/tagged/log4j)) level. I don't think there is any general support for that, but I think it is a great idea to implement this. I will have a look, maybe it is not that much work.

UPDATE: I implemented [filtering irrelevant stack trace lines in logs](https://www.nurkiewicz.com/2012/03/filtering-irrelevant-stack-trace-lines.html) for [logback](/questions/tagged/logback), also follow [LBCLASSIC-325](https://jira.qos.ch/browse/LBCLASSIC-325).

Comment: unfortunately, the intelliJ plugin is not compatible anymore. (at least with 03/17 ubuntu build)

Answer (score 15):

I actually wrote an open source library MgntUtils  (available at [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt) and [maven central](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.github.michaelgantman%20AND%20a:MgntUtils))
that contains several utilities. Here is a link to an article about the library: [MgntUtils Open Source Java library](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/open-source-java-library-some-useful-utilities-michael-gantman/). One of the utilities is a general purpose stacktrace 
filter that I used extensively and found it very useful. The class is called 
TextUtils and it has method getStacktrace() with several overridden signatures.
It takes a Throwable instance and allows to set a package prefix of the packages
that are relevant. Let's say your company's code always resides in packages that 
start with "com.plain.*" So you set such a prefix and do this

```
logger.info(TextUtils.getStacktrace(e, true, "com.plain."));
```

this will filter out very smartly all the useless parts of the trace leaving
 you with very concise stacktrace. Also I found it very convinient to pre-set the 
prefix and then just use the convinience method

```
TextUtils.getStacktrace(e);
```

It will do the same. To preset the prefix just use method

```
setRelevantPackage("com.plain.");
```

Also if you use Spring environment you can add the following segment to your
 Spring configuration and then you all set:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
  <property name="targetClass" value="com.mgnt.utils.TextUtils"/>
  <property name="targetMethod" value="setRelevantPackage"/>
  <property name="arguments" value="com.plain."/>
</bean>
```

The library comes with well written (I hope) [Javadoc](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/) that explains everything in detail. But here is a little teaser: you will get a following stacktrace:

```
at com.plain.BookService.listBooks()
at com.plain.BookService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$e7645040.invoke()
at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke()
...
at com.plain.LoggingAspect.logging()
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0()
...
at com.plain.BookService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$7cb147e4.listBooks()
at com.plain.web.BookController.listBooks()
```

instead of

```
at com.plain.BookService.listBooks()
at com.plain.BookService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$e7645040.invoke()
at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke()
at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint()
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed()
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed()
at com.plain.LoggingAspect.logging()
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0()
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke()
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke()
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke()
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs()
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod()
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke()
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed()
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AbstractTraceInterceptor.invoke()
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed()
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke()
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed()
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke()
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed()
at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept()
at com.plain.BookService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$7cb147e4.listBooks()
at com.plain.web.BookController.listBooks()
```

Comment: great library! There's a similar feature in log4j2 to exclude packages from the stacktrace.

Comment: @gaurav - First of all thanks. Also, I would be very interested in more detailed feedback on the library if you have anything to say about it. Please look me up on LinkedIn (https://www.linkedin.com/in/michael-gantman-9661521/) and if you can write me a bit more, please

Answer (score 2):

For log4j:

```
package package1;

public class FilteringThrowableRenderer implements ThrowableRenderer {
    private static final String PACKAGES_SEPARATOR = "\\s*,\\s*";

    private final static String TRACE_PREFIX = "\tat ";

    private static final String FILTERED_WARNING = " [Stacktrace is filtered]";

    ThrowableRenderer defaultRenderer = new EnhancedThrowableRenderer();

    List<String> skippedLinePrefixes;

    public FilteringThrowableRenderer() {
        String skippedPackagesString = "java,org"; // TODO: move it to config
        String[] skippedPackages =
            skippedPackagesString.trim().split(PACKAGES_SEPARATOR);
        skippedLinePrefixes = new ArrayList<String>(skippedPackages.length);
        for (String packageName : skippedPackages) {
            skippedLinePrefixes.add(TRACE_PREFIX + packageName);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String[] doRender(Throwable throwable) {
        String[] initialTrace = defaultRenderer.doRender(throwable);
        if (!skippedLinePrefixes.isEmpty()) {
            List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>(initialTrace.length);

            boolean filtered = false;
            trace: for (String element : initialTrace) {
                for (String skippedLinePrefix : skippedLinePrefixes) {
                    if (element.startsWith(skippedLinePrefix)) {
                        filtered = true;
                        continue trace;
                    }
                }
                result.add(element);
            }
            if (filtered && result.size() > 0) {
                result.set(0, result.get(0) + FILTERED_WARNING);
            }
            return result.toArray(new String[result.size()]);
        } else {
            return initialTrace;
        }
    }
}
```

to enable it with code:

```
ThrowableRendererSupport loggerRepository =
    (ThrowableRendererSupport) LogManager.getLoggerRepository();
loggerRepository.setThrowableRenderer(new FilteringThrowableRenderer());
```

or with log4j.properties:

```
log4j.throwableRenderer=package1.FilteringThrowableRenderer
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you are looking for (and, to the best of my knowledge, there is no universal solution for your problem, at least I've never heard of a famous tool to clean and extract info from Java stacktraces).

Anyway, [this post from July, 05, 2011 at Faux' Blog](https://blog.goeswhere.com/2011/06/java-stacktraces-straw-man/) describes a Java Agent in early stages whose purpose is to enrich (and not filter) stack traces. It evens provide a link to a git repository with a mavenized project. Maybe you can go from here, tweak his code and roll your own solution (who knows, maybe even start an open source project).

Comment: I've seen that, but was hoping I wouldn't have to write my own. Seems like the way to go though.

Answer (score 1):

This plugin's pretty nice

```
https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/grep-console
```

Just a generalized grep formatting utility for the Eclipse console, so no additional dependencies.  I format all my irrelevant noise to grey text.