# Minimize content of the Java stack trace

Tags: java, exception, stack, trace

I'm looking for an approach that would give me the flexibility to specify what should be printed. For example, I want my stack trace to only have the filename:line_number printed. I don't want the package name and function name.

Comment: I would recommend you remove the "asking for a library" part of your question, as this is off-topic on stackoverflow, and may attract off-topic close votes

Comment: why is it off-topic though? People do ask about libraries here @Ferrybig

Comment: Asking for libraries is off topic on stackoverflow, and usually gets closed pretty quick.

Comment: You'll need a logging framework for that, and then you need to configure the logging settings to display what you want.

Comment: @Kayaman we are using log4j right now

Comment: The reason that they are off-topic is: **1:** Top voted answer can get outdated, making them less useful for future visitors, **2:** They attract spam quickly, if people want to vote for a library, people need to download the library, and virus checking on this is hard **3:** A link that was first a library, can be changed to a virus site if the domain expires. For more information, see [What exactly is a recommendation question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question)

Comment: @FaizHalde Good for you. Now read the documentation for it.

Comment: If you just want that for JUnit test, you can filter out the Class in Eclipse setting. \ But its not as fine control as OP wants. \ Another related article about colorizing: https://dzone.com/articles/filtering-stack-trace-hell \ Another related post about Log4j https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33220719/can-the-stacktrace-in-spring-boot-be-reduced \ Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606614/cleaning-noise-out-of-java-stack-traces

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write an own utility method for that:

Given an `Throwable e` get the list of `StackTraceElement`

```
StackTraceElement[] elems = e.getStackTrace();
```

then loop over the elements and print the information you want, using `StackTraceElement.getFileName()` and `getLineNumber()`